# what are the differences between having a .EXE file which is scheduled using Windows Task Scheduler and between having Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I know that creating a Windows Service allow us to run background jobs without having to login to the machine. while `.exe` files can be run when users login to their PC and click on the `.exe` file (require user to be login).

But now let say i create a `.exe` file and i schedule it to run using windows Task Scheduler. where i can specify to run the task even when the user is not login.. so in this case what will be the real difference between :-

1. Having a `.exe` which is scheduled to run using task scheduler?
2. and between having a windows service ?

Thanks

Comment: Service for example runs continuously, while scheduled task runs at specified intervals.

Comment: If you can do what you want with task scheduler, do so.

Comment: @Evk so what are other things that can only be found on a .exe or only on windows service ??

Comment: @Ben can you explain why ? and what will .exe provide which windows service can not and vice versa ??

Comment: If you need to run something say once per hour - why unnecessary hold a process in memory continuously (as in service)?  Use task scheduler.

Comment: I could probably be more helpful if I had some idea what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ben i want to run a background task which check for .csv file inside a folder , then update the database with the .csv data.. so the database will always be in sysnc with the auto generated .csv file.. now we do not have any predefined periods when a the .csv file is created.. this .csv file is managed by our ERP system (3rd party application) and it generates this .csv file when new assets are added to our ERP system..

Comment: I suggest a scheduled task, or if the folder is on SQL Server, you can use a SQLAgent job. Since this is a server thing, battery usage is not an issue, so a job checking once per minute is OK.

Comment: @Ben but if i write a windows service.. then how will the windows service work will it do the check each second since it run continuously ???

Comment: The service will do whatever you tell it to do. But what you have here is a really basic task that many devs have done many times. You don't want a service for this.

Answer (score 2):

Task Scheduler is generally suitable for processes which carry out periodic or occasional tasks, anything from once per minute, to "at logon" or "once per year". They can be made to effectively run continuously too, but that's really an abuse of the system.

Task Scheduler can also run processes in the context of the logged-on user, and such processes can interact with the user.

Services are generally suitable for processes which run continuously, such as those servicing devices, or providing network services.

Services generally cannot interact directly with the user. Where they need to do this, there is generally a user program which communicates with the service via some sort of RPC, such as DCOM, MSRPC or something else.

There isn't really anything a service can do which a program started by Task Scheduler cannot, or vice-versa: These capabilities depend on the login identity that the program runs under, not on how they are started.

Summary:

- If you want a continuous process which provides services to the network, you probably want a service.
- If the process is slow to start up, but cheap to keep going once running, you probably want a service.
- If you want to perform periodic tasks of any kind, you probably want a scheduled task.
- If the process is expensive or intensive in CPU or disk usage, you probably want to rewrite it so that it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But let me rephrase my question... Now if we want to compare their internal life cycles then are there any differences between the 2 approaches ? The way i understand things is as follow:- When I (or the task scheduler) execute a .exe, then the .exe will start executing till the end and the .exe file will no longer be active once it completed its execution.... but in the windows service case ,,, once the windows serve start it will continue executing until we shut show the whole PC?? or this is not the case exactly??

Comment: The service can choose to stop any time it likes, or the service control manager can request it to stop.

Comment: So mainly the life cycles for both approaches are almost the same ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your software do whatever it has to do correctly, there will not be any differences. It all depends in what approach you want to give to your development. I usually try to involve the less components I can in this kind of solution just to make easier the troubleshooting and manteinance. For example If you install your `.exe` and configure it as a scheduled task, whenever it fails you will have to check not only what is inherent to your software but all what is involved in a scheduled task (user, schedules, triggers, services), and you not always will be able to control that, as your application may be installed on a server you do not have full rights to do what you want.

Also, take in consideration that every scheduled task depends on the `Task Scheduler` which is a service himself.

So to resume: The advanteges of creating a Job IMHO, is avoiding to recreate all the scheduled-triggered logic that might be a headache to develop if you have not done it before. And it is not better to reinvent the wheel. In the other hand, if you have some clear task that can be done with a `Timer` then it will probably be a better option just to create a Windows Service.

Comment: the intend of my question is to know exactly the differences between these 2 approachies.. before start to judging which appraoch is better and easier to develop and maintain ... as seems both approaches are somehow similar .. in respect that both can run even if users are not login... and both can be started manually and both can run under specific user account...

Comment: @johnG Looking at your comments I can see you need to look for CSV files in a specific directory. I´ve made several projects of this kind. IMHO the best thing to do in this case is to have a Timer and look for the files in the folder or just create a FileSystemWatcher to know if some file have been moved to the location and then fire your logic.

Comment: so seems to my both approaches are somehow similar but if i chose to use .exe which is scheduled using Task Scheduler, then i will add extra dependency on my application (which is the Task Scheduler itself).. while in the windows service it will be self contained ,, it will know when it should start working without additional components...is this correct ? second question if we compare their life cycles will they also have similar life cycles ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add here that windows service (schedule tasks) deployment is in developers hand. A developer can write a code to do change the process execution time at any point of time.
At other hand process run through "task scheduler " are dependent to the server admin. Developer has to guide the admin about what time scheduler must run. 
If there is any requirement to run the process at some irregular time, they have to approach to server admin, either to run the .EXE manually for now and also change the scheduler time. 
In other case admin only need to restart the service, he will not have any concern about the time!!!